# template __thread initializer with clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, thread-local-storage

I'm using `__thread` with clang.

Yes, I know it's non-portable.  Yes, I know of the standard C++ `thread_local` keyword.  I am aware of the differences.  In this case, I am purposely using `__thread`.

Now, with both Clang and G++, the `__thread` keyword can only be used with POD types that have trivial destructors.

For example:

```
struct Foo {}; 
__thread Foo f;
```

However, it seems that Clang prohibits the use of `__thread` where the type depends on a template parameter - even if the template itself is never instantiated (and thus Clang has no way to even tell yet if the type is a POD with a trivial destructor.)

For example, with GCC 4.9.2, I can say:

```
template <class T>
struct Bar { T data; };

template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    static __thread Bar<T> value;
};

template <class T>
__thread Bar<T> Foo<T>::value {};

Foo<int> f;
```

This compiles and works fine.

But with Clang 4.0, the exact same code says:

```
error: initializer for thread-local variable must be a constant expression
__thread Bar<T> Foo<T>::value {};
```

Even if I remove the line `Foo<int> f`, so that the template itself is never even instantiated, Clang still gives the error.

So it looks like Clang just doesn't support this.  Is this documented anywhere, or is this just a bug in Clang?  The only documentation for `__thread` with Clang I can find indicates it should work with any POD type.  But here, Clang doesn't check if the type is a POD or not, since it errors before the template is even instantiated.

So is this a bug in Clang?  Is there any known work-around?

**EDIT:** I can get it to work in Clang if I remove the `{}` initializer, like:

```
template <class T>
__thread Bar<T> Foo<T>::value;
```

This may be a possible workaround, but I'm uncertain if this is safe.  I want to make sure the thread local value is zero-initialized.  The documentation doesn't seem to specify whether an object with `__thread` storage is necessarily zero-initialized.  I would think it would be, if it is `static`, but I'd rather explicitly specify an initializer.  Unfortunately, Clang doesn't like that.

Comment: Seeing the same issue here. Looks like a bug?